# Identifying microcontroller ic (54281)

Tags: microcontroller, identification

I would like to understand how a toy helicopter works, and modify it.

For that, I want to identify the microcontroller it uses, but I have no idea…

The only thing I have, is 54281 written on it.

[image: photo of the circuit]

Do you have any idea or advice on how to identify it ?

Comment: Step 1: Where's your schematic?

Comment: It may not even be a microcontroller but a custom IC for the job.

Comment: I've never seen an IC with such weird font formatting.

Comment: An advice would be to reverse engineer the circuit and try to make a circuit diagram of the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian Dummond said in the comments, it's probably not even a microcontroller.

You might want to use and logic analyser / oscilloscope to monitor its ins and out, and reverse engineer it. 
You would also have to try and make a circuit diagram, as Bradman175 said.

This label seems to be only a part number and not an actual reference. We couldn't tell you wich IC it is, even if it wasn't custom.

EDIT : this seems to me like the helicopter is a remote controlled helicopter, probably infra-red so I'd say the IC is a custom IC that decodes the IR signal and drives the motors accordingly. What do you think if when saying "modify it"? I don't think there's much to do except removing all the card and keeping just the electro-mechanics (ie the battery, the motor, the wings...) to add your own command electronics.

Comment: It is this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0CPHxyZR40

Comment: My goal would be to make it behave differently that it does now (allowing it to go up if it receive an IR signal from the remote instead of… doing nothing)

Comment: Well as I said, best is to remove the electronics and recreate a crcuit of your own. This IC does not seem like a microcontroller that you could reprogram.